# Installing Manjaro on an SSD and Switching Mac Mini Hard Drive

Tags: mac, install, ssd, unix, mac-mini

I have an old Mac Mini Core Solo (2006 model). I wanted to know if it's possible to install Manjaro on an SSD and then swap the old Mac drive with the Manjaro SSD? I've tried using Rufus to make a bootable SSD and when I installed it in the Mac, all I get is a blank gray screen. I was hoping to get to an install screen but no luck. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What file did you download? Can you give a link?

Comment: If you are installing 32 bit Manjaro 18.0.4, then you will need at least 1 GB of memory. Your Mac started witn 512 MB and can go up to 2 GB.

Comment: Can I assume you did not try the optical drive for installation?

Comment: I used the 64 bit version located here https://manjaro.org/downloads/official/kde/

Comment: I did not go the optical route as for reasons I don't know I'm unable to boot from a dvd. I could give it another shot and see if it works (I haven't tried with Manjaro yet. I should also add that I'm not getting any registering of keystrokes using a wired keyboard.

Comment: Does the computer have enough memory?

Comment: I think so. It's 512MB. Should I have tried the 32 bit instead?

Comment: Oh ok. Did your mac already have an OS running? I totally screwed my OS up and couldn't it to boot in any mode. My thought was to 1. Install linux on a different SSD 2. Swap out the old Mac drive with the linux one. 3) Boot into linux with the new SSD installed. I'm not sure if that is a even possible but I was hoping so. I'll take a look at VirtualBox maybe it could help. I'm wondering if I just need to reinstall Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

Rufus to use to make a bootable USB flash drive. In your case, you are suppose to boot from the flash drive to software that can install Manjaro on another drive. Usually, this is the the computers internal drive.

What you propose to do has the following flaws.

- You want Rufus to put the software on the SSD drive you intend to install internal in the computer, instead of a USB flash drive.
- You have not drive to install Manjaro on to. In other words, if you did get the SSD to boot from the Manjaro installation software put there by Rufus, then this software could not install to the internal drive because that is where the Manjaro installation software resides.

Additionally, the standard RAM that came with this model Mac was 512 MB. To install Manjaro, you need at least 1 GB of RAM. If you do not have enough RAM memory, then you can upgrade. I would recommend 2 GB of RAM. One such source is [OWC](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/5300DDR2S2GP/).

You can not install any 64 bit version of Manjaro, because the processor in your Mac mini is 32 bit. AFAIK, the latest 32 bit version of Manjaro available for download is [manjaro-xfce-18.0.4-x32-stable-minimal-i686.iso](https://osdn.net/projects/manjaro32/storage/xfce/18.0.4/).